# Which material is better at bouncing back an electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, material-science

Which material is better at bouncing back an electromagnetic wave?

- Diamagnetic
- Paramagnetic
- Ferrimagnetic
- Ferromagnetic

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the values of the dielectric and para- or diamagnetic constants, $\varepsilon \And \mu $, defined by $D=\varepsilon E$ and $B=\mu H$.  The phase velocity of waves in the material will depend on the product, $c'=c/\sqrt{\mu \varepsilon }$, but the material’s *impedance* will depend on the ratio, $z\equiv \sqrt{\mu /\varepsilon }$.  The fraction of power reflected will be ${{(1-z)}^{2}}/{{(1+z)}^{2}}$.  A paramagnetic material $(\mu >1)$ that is also dielectric $(\varepsilon >1)$ will be a poor reflector.  The very best reflector would be a perfectly diamagnetic $(\mu =0)$ material such as a superconductor.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want a conductor with no magnetic properties of its own that will interfere with the movement of charge within it. That is, option 5, not magnetic.